# How to create a Texture from a ArrayBuffer in html5 and WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl, babylonjs

I am having a image that I am reading in server side and pushing to web browser via AJAX call.
I have a requirement where I have to render them line by line using WebGL.

For Example : Image is 640X480 where 640 is width and 480 is height.
Now the total number of pixels will be 640*480 = 307200 pixels. 
So, I want to render the whole image in 640(total width) intervals in a loop using WebGL.

Now I have texture2D(as per my knowledge) in webgl to do so, but not getting any idea of where to start .
I also having the ArrayBuffer with me , only thing is using Texture2D I want to render it slowly ,line by line.

I am ready to go for any js libraries ,if they are satisfying the requirements.

Tagging Babylon.js and Three.js ,incase those guys have a answer to my question with what they already have.

Adding some code to explain my requirement :

```
//Recieve data
Code : 
var imageDataFromServer = single line data from server;
var imageLineData = new ArrayBuffer(imageDataFromServer.length);
var imageUintArray = new Uint8Array(imageLineData);
for (var i = 0; i < width(i.e.640) ;i++) //because I know one line length =640.
{
   //how to put data in texture2D using Three.js or Babylon.js or just plain WebGL
}
```

Comment: [Start Here](http://webglfundamentals.org)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, below is the working code
1) put it into .html file
2) load image (see comment in initTextures function)

In this code is also added vertex and fragment shaders

```
<canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
function initShaders(gl, vshader, fshader) {
  var program = createProgram(gl, vshader, fshader);    
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.program = program;

  return true;
}

function createProgram(gl, vshader, fshader) {
  var vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vshader);
  var fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fshader);
  var program = gl.createProgram();

  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);

  gl.linkProgram(program);
  return program;
}

function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
  var shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  return shader;
}

function getWebGLContext(canvas, opt_debug) {
  return canvas.getContext('webgl');
}

var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
  'attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;\n' +
  'varying vec2 uv;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
  '  uv = a_TexCoord;\n' +
  '}\n';

var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  '#ifdef GL_ES\n' +
  'precision mediump float;\n' +
  '#endif\n' +
  'uniform sampler2D uImage0;\n' +
  'uniform vec2 resolution;\n' +
  'uniform float time;\n' +
  'varying vec2 uv;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
      'vec2 position = 1.0 - gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution;\n' +
      'vec3 color = vec3(1.0);\n' +

      'if (time > position.y * 10.0) {\n' +
          'color = vec3(texture2D(uImage0, uv));\n' +
      '}\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);\n' +
  '}\n';

function main() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
  initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE);

  var n = initVertexBuffers(gl);
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  initTextures(gl, n)

  function render (dt) {
    gl.uniform1f(time, dt / 1000);
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  render();
}

function initVertexBuffers(gl) {
  var verticesTexCoords = new Float32Array([
    -0.5,  0.5,   0.0, 1.0,
    -0.5, -0.5,   0.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5,   1.0, 1.0,
     0.5, -0.5,   1.0, 0.0,
  ]);
  var n = 4;
  var vertexTexCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexTexCoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesTexCoords, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var FSIZE = verticesTexCoords.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 4, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

  var a_TexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_TexCoord');
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_TexCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 4, FSIZE * 2);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_TexCoord);

  return n;
}

function initTextures(gl, n) {
  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'resolution');
  gl.uniform2f(resolution, 256, 256);
  time = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'time');

  var uImage0 = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'uImage0');

  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function(){ loadTexture(gl, n, texture, uImage0, image); };

  // load this file: http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/tutorials/easy-hidpi/chrome1x.png
  // to the same folder as this .html file
  image.src = 'chrome1x.png';

  return true;
}

function loadTexture(gl, n, texture, uImage0, image) {
  count = n;
  GL = gl;

  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, 1);
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  gl.uniform1i(uImage0, 0);

  draw();
}

function draw () {
  if (!window.GL) {
    return;
  }
  GL.clear(GL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  GL.drawArrays(GL.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, count);
}

main();
</script>
```

Comment: Answer is not exact but gave some hope, I want to learn GLSL, any good references. Because down the line, I will be writing custom filters in GLSL,\but I really don't know where to start learning that.

Comment: Check this sites: glslsandbox.com, shadertoy.com. See cool examples for inspiration and simple stuff for learning basic techniques. See also this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0EpikNmjs2CYUMePMGh3IjjP4tQlYqji Also check this cool book: http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-Shading-Language-Cookbook-Edition/dp/1782167021/ref=pd_sim_14_1?ie=UTF8&dpID=51hR5S3JynL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR130%2C160_&refRID=037AZ70R8P7BGPNP7A61

Comment: yes they are good to start. I don't know c++, I know javascript, java, will it be easy for me if I purchase that amazon kindle

Comment: I you see this [link](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/11405-is-possible-to-load-textures-from-a-arraybufferview/) , this guy has the same problem, which means it is also possible in three/babylon

Comment: Can you help me with writing the javascript part of it. (http://glslsandbox.com/e#30724.0) , I have commented out line no. 15 as it was giving me compilation error I am still trying but as I am newbie in glsl ,so not getting any idea of how to write the Javascript part of it

Comment: I am writing another answer (I know that's not correct , but if you can correct me that will be great )

Answer (score 0):

So, to write a image line by line we can do something like this.

**Vertex Shader**

- ```
  attribute vec2 a_position;?
  attribute vec2 a_texCoord;?

  void main() {
     ???
  }
  ```
- **Fragment Shader**

  ```
   #ifdef GL_ES
   precision mediump float;
   #endif

  uniform float time;
  uniform vec2 mouse;
  uniform vec2 resolution;

  void main( void ) {
    vec2 position = 1.0 - gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution;
    vec3 color = vec3(1.0);

    if (time > position.y * 10.0) {
        color = texture2D(uImage0, uv);
    }

   gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);

  }
  ```
- **Javascript For rendering pixel by pixel**

  ```
    function createTextureFromArray(gl, dataArray, type, width, height) {
          var data = new Uint8Array(dataArray);
          var texture = gl.createTexture();
          gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
          gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, type, width, height, 0, type, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
          return texture;
   }

     var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(640*480);
     for (var i=0; i < 640; i++) {
         for (var j=0; j < 480; j++) {
             arrayBuffer[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0;     //filling buffer with random data between 0 and 255 which will be further filled to the texture 
             //NOTE : above data is just dummy data , I will get this data from server pixel by pixel.
         }
     }
     var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
     // setup GLSL program
     var program = createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
     gl.useProgram(program);
     //what should I add after this ?
  ```

Comment: Ok, check my fully solution for that.

Comment: Okay the answer is closer now, just 2 more things , 1)Instead of animation from top ,can I do that from left or right? <br/> 2) It is not working if I put any other image instead of that .

Comment: There are two reason why it may not work: cross-origin mistakes if you try to load image from another host, or image is not power of two (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent).

Comment: Loading from local only , It however loads but darkens . I mean the image doesn't come properly