# How to render images in WebGL from ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, babylonjs

I am having a image that I am reading in server side and pushing to web browser via AJAX call. I have a requirement where I have to render them line by line using WebGL.

For Example : Image is 640X480 where 640 is width and 480 is height. Now the total number of pixels will be 640*480 = 307200 pixels. So, I want to render the whole image in 640(total width) intervals in a loop using WebGL.

Now I have texture2D(as per my knowledge) in webgl to do so, but not getting any idea of where to start . I also having the ArrayBuffer with me , only thing is using Texture2D I want to render it slowly ,line by line.

I am ready to go for any js libraries ,if they are satisfying the requirements.
So, to write a image line by line we can do something like this.

**Vertex Shader**

- ```
  attribute vec2 a_position;?
  attribute vec2 a_texCoord;?

  void main() {
     ???
  }
  ```
- **Fragment Shader**

  ```
   #ifdef GL_ES
   precision mediump float;
   #endif

  uniform float time;
  uniform vec2 mouse;
  uniform vec2 resolution;

  void main( void ) {
    vec2 position = 1.0 - gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution;
    vec3 color = vec3(1.0);

    if (time > position.y * 10.0) {
        color = texture2D(uImage0, uv);
    }

   gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);

  }
  ```
- **Javascript For rendering pixel by pixel**

  ```
    function createTextureFromArray(gl, dataArray, type, width, height) {
          var data = new Uint8Array(dataArray);
          var texture = gl.createTexture();
          gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
          gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, type, width, height, 0, type, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
          return texture;
   }

     var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(640*480);
     for (var i=0; i < 640; i++) {
         for (var j=0; j < 480; j++) {
             arrayBuffer[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0;     //filling buffer with random data between 0 and 255 which will be further filled to the texture 
             //NOTE : above data is just dummy data , I will get this data from server pixel by pixel.
         }
     }
     var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
     // setup GLSL program
     var program = createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
     gl.useProgram(program);
     //what should I add after this ?
  ```

  Can anybody complete the code , I have no idea of how to write code to accomplish this.

Comment: Didn't you already asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269496/how-to-create-a-texture-from-a-arraybuffer-in-html5-and-webgl) before?

Comment: "Can anybody complete the code": SO is not a please write my code site.

Comment: I asked because WEBGL has very less/limited tutorials and I can see that GLSL is essential here. Hence, I asked if someone can just show me a path of where to go with some proper code. And I can then play around that piece of code

Comment: Check this tutorial: webglfundamentals.org

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is not designed to draw images "line by line." However, you can achieve this effect in software by writing to an array, uploading it as a texture, and sampling from it in your shader when drawing a full screen polygon.

To go about this you should create an unsigned byte array. For each pixel in your image you can have some combination of red, green, blue, and alpha channels. The simplest case would be RGB, 3 unsigned bytes for each pixel. The final array should be sized according to the component size (3), times your width (640), times your height (480). You should initialize the values in your array according to what you want your background color to be, then upload it to the gpu using texImage2D.

To 'draw line by line' would be to update 'width' pixels at a time given a row. Each time you change the image data you should then reupload the image to the gpu then draw the fullscreen polygon.

The fullscreen polygon is simply two triangles that cover the entire clip space of the screen. The screen goes from -1 to 1 in x and y dimensions, so make an array buffer accordingly, upload it with the two triangles, and call drawArrays as you update the texture. The UV's for the polygon should go from 0 to 1, so in your vertex shader you should have a 'varying' output variable that will be 0.5 * position + 0.5. This is used in the fragment shader to sample from the texture.

The official documentation is one of the best places to learn from. The official reference pages for openGL ES or openGL 3 contain relevant information, while the reference card https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf show the available functions in WebGL that correspond roughly to the same api.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear at all what you're trying to accomplish and why you are using WebGL at all. Are you sending one line of data at a time and you want to render that one individual line of data when its received? Are you sending all the data and you just want reveal it a line at time horizontally?

If you have the entire image available then you can just render a larger and larger portion of it using canvas2d. The `drawImage` function takes optional source and destination rectangles.

```
// at init time
var x = 0;

// at render time
while (x < img.width) {
  var srcX = x;
  var srcY = 0;
  var srcWidth = 1;  // one pixel per frame
  var srcHeight = img.height;
  var dstX = x;
  var dstY = 0;
  var dstWidth = 1;
  var dstHeight = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight, dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight);
  ++x;
}
```

If you're sending them 1 line of data at a time you can use `ImageData` to make a 1xheight image and use `putImageData` to draw it.

```
// at init time or whenever you know the height
var imageData = ctx.createImageData(1, height);
var x = 0;

// on received next line of data
for (var ii = 0; ii < imageData.length; ++ii) {
  imageData.data[ii] = receivedColumnOfPixels[ii];
}

ctx.putImageData(imageData, x, 0);
++x;
```

If you want to scale the `ImageData` put it in a second canvas and use that canvas as input to `drawImage` using the first technique.

You can do the same things in WebGL. If you have the entire texture in memory then each frame adjust your positions and texture coordinates to draw a different part of it. If you're receiving 1 column of data at a time then just use a texture that's 1 x height and draw that at the appropriate place. OR, copy that 1 x height data into the fullsize texture using `gl.texSubImage2D` and then adjust the positions and texture coordinates appropriately to draw the part of the texture you want to draw to the part of the canvas you want to draw it.

`drawImage` implemented in WebGL would look something like this. I'm using [twgl.js](http://twgljs.org) because WebGL is too verbose.

```js
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl");
// compiles shader, links and looks up locations
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

// a unit quad
var arrays = {
  position: { 
    numComponents: 2, 
    data: [
      0, 0,  
      1, 0, 
      0, 1, 
      0, 1, 
      1, 0,  
      1, 1,
    ],
  },
};
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

// create a texture using a canvas so we don't have to download one
var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
["red", "orange", "yellow"].forEach(function(color, ndx, array) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc((ndx + 1) / (array.length + 1) * ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height / 2, ctx.canvas.height * 0.4, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.stroke();
});
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.font = "40px sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("DrawImage", ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2);

// calls gl.createTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.texImage2D, gl.texParameteri
var tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, { src: ctx.canvas });
var texWidth  = ctx.canvas.width;
var texHeight = ctx.canvas.height;

// we pass in texWidth and texHeight because unlike images
// we can't look up the width and height of a texture

// we pass in targetWidth and targetHeight to tell it
// the size of the thing we're drawing too. We could look 
// up the size of the canvas with gl.canvas.width and
// gl.canvas.height but maybe we want to draw to a framebuffer
// etc.. so might as well pass those in.

// srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight are in pixels 
// computed from texWidth and texHeight

// dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight are in pixels
// computed from targetWidth and targetHeight
function drawImage(
    tex, texWidth, texHeight,
    srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight,
    dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight,
    targetWidth, targetHeight) {
  var mat  = m4.identity();
  var tmat = m4.identity();
  
  var uniforms = {
    matrix: mat,
    textureMatrix: tmat,
    texture: tex,
  };

  // these adjust the unit quad to generate texture coordinates
  // to select part of the src texture

  // NOTE: no check is done that srcX + srcWidth go outside of the
  // texture or are in range in any way. Same for srcY + srcHeight

  m4.translate(tmat, [srcX / texWidth, srcY / texHeight, 0], tmat);
  m4.scale(tmat, [srcWidth / texWidth, srcHeight / texHeight, 1], tmat);

  // these convert from pixels to clip space
  m4.translate(mat, [-1, 1, 0], mat);
  m4.scale(mat, [2 / targetWidth, -2 / targetHeight, 1], mat); 

  // these move and scale the unit quad into the size we want
  // in the target as pixels
  m4.translate(mat, [dstX, dstY, 0], mat);
  m4.scale(mat, [dstWidth, dstHeight, 1], mat);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  // calls gl.uniformXXX, gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  // calls gl.drawArray or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);
  
}
  
function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  var targetWidth  = gl.canvas.width;
  var targetHeight = gl.canvas.height;

  // pick some various src rects and dst rects
  var srcX = Math.abs(Math.sin(time * 1   )) * texWidth;
  var srcY = Math.abs(Math.sin(time * 1.81)) * texHeight;
  var srcWidth  = (texWidth  - srcX) * Math.abs(Math.sin(time * 2.12));
  var srcHeight = (texHeight - srcY) * Math.abs(Math.sin(time * 1.53));

  var dstX = Math.abs(Math.sin(time * 0.34)) * targetWidth;
  var dstY = Math.abs(Math.sin(time * 2.75)) * targetHeight;
  var dstWidth  = (targetWidth  - dstX) * Math.abs(Math.sin(time * 1.16));
  var dstHeight = (targetHeight - dstY) * Math.abs(Math.sin(time * 1.17));
  
  drawImage(
    tex, texWidth, texHeight,  
    srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight,
    dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight,
    targetWidth, targetHeight);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script id="vs" type="not-js">
// we will always pass a 0 to 1 unit quad
// and then use matrices to manipulate it
attribute vec4 position;   

uniform mat4 matrix;
uniform mat4 textureMatrix;

varying vec2 texcoord;

void main () {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
  
  texcoord = (textureMatrix * position).xy;
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="not-js">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 texcoord;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texcoord);
}
</script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

To understand them matrix math [see these articles](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) and work your way backward or forward in those articles.

Comment: Just for my own checking [here's a fiddle using the above code AND drawing to a 2d canvas using `drawImage`](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/y4bhLq1w/) to check the results are the same.